# How do I pass multiple parameters to a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I have 1 batch file. I have 5 data files that are located in 5 different folders. Data structures are the same: Same numbers of columns, same filenames but only the contents are different.How do I pass multiple parameters to a batch file?  Here is an example loading data for 1 folder. How do I do for data located in 4 others folders(Folder2….Folder5)? Please I need your help.

```
@echo off
for %%F in ("C:\Temp\Folder1\*.txt") do (
sqlldr USERID=xyz/xyz@db CONTROL='C:\Temp\Folder1\TEST.ctl' 
LOG='C:\Temp\Folder1\TEST.log' "DATA=%%F"
goto AfterLoop
)
:AfterLoop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea how to use the tool and have never read the help/usage information, so this is an assumption only:

```bat
@Echo Off
For %%A In (1 2 3 4 5) Do (
    PushD "C:\Temp\Folder%%A"
    SQLLdr USERID=xyz/xyz@db CONTROL=TEST LOG=TEST DATA=*.txt
    PopD
)

:AfterLoop
```

If `DATA` doesn't accept the wildcard then, perhaps adding a nested loop would do it:

```bat
@Echo Off
For %%A In (1 2 3 4 5) Do (
    PushD "C:\Temp\Folder%%A"
    For %%B In (*.txt) Do (
        SQLLdr USERID=xyz/xyz@db CONTROL=TEST LOG=TEST DATA='%%B'
    )
    PopD
)

:AfterLoop
```

And of course, because you're almost guaranteed to now inform us that the folder names were not accurate, you could adjust it similarly:

```bat
@Echo Off
For %%A In (
    "C:\Temp\Folder1"
    "C:\Temp\Folder2"
    "C:\Temp\Folder3"
    "C:\Temp\Folder4"
    "C:\Temp\Folder5"
) Do (
    PushD "%%A"
    SQLLdr USERID=xyz/xyz@db CONTROL=TEST LOG=TEST DATA=*.txt
    PopD
)

:AfterLoop
```

Or:

```bat
@Echo Off
For %%A In (
    "C:\Temp\Folder1"
    "C:\Temp\Folder2"
    "C:\Temp\Folder3"
    "C:\Temp\Folder4"
    "C:\Temp\Folder5"
) Do (
    PushD "%%A"
    For %%B In (*.txt) Do (
        SQLLdr USERID=xyz/xyz@db CONTROL=TEST LOG=TEST DATA='%%B'
    )
    PopD
)

:AfterLoop
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. It's very useful. Yes, the folders are all at the same level. Folder1 ... .to folder5 were just one example, but the real name of the folders are SV.DE, DS, DA and DF. I took 5 files as an example, but in reality, I get 44 data sources per day, so I create 44 folders. The first example would be close to what I'm looking for. I have not tried yet but I will let you know the result. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the folders are all on the same level.  You can get a list of the folders by using a `FOR /D` command.

```
FOR /D %%G IN (C:\temp\*) DO ...
```

Then you can use that as part of your inner `FOR` command:

```
FOR %%F IN ("%%G\*.txt") do ....
```

So if you put it all together it would look something lik this.

```
@echo off
FOR /D %%G IN (C:\temp\*) DO (
    for %%F in ("%%G\*.txt") do (
        sqlldr USERID=xyz/xyz@db CONTROL='%%G\TEST.ctl' LOG='%%G\TEST.log' "DATA=%%F"
    )
)
```